# Trying to get property of non-object in edit.blade.php(laravel 4.2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

While editing the blade file for multi select field, I'm getting property of non-object in my `edit.blade.php` file.

**In View File:**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail">Department </label>
    <select name="department_id[]" id="department_id" class="chkveg" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        @foreach($dept as $depts)
        <option value="{{$depts->value}}" {{ $dept_data->department_id == $depts->value ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>
            {{$depts->dept}}
        </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**In Controller File:**

```
$dept = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT m.name as dept, m.value as value 
                    FROM master_lookup as m JOIN lookup_categories as l 
                    l.id = m.category_id WHERE m.category_id = 34"));  
$dept_data = DB::table('user_department')
                    ->where('user_id',$user_id)
                    ->get();
//dd($dept_data);
return View::make('users.edit')->with(array(
    'dept'      => $dept,
    'dept_data' => $dept_data
));
```

Comment: What are the results of `dd($dept)`? Which object is it complaining about specifically, `$depts` or `$dept_data`?

Comment: The $dept data is looks like below:                                                 
 array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1831 (2) { ["dept"]=> string(5) "Sales" ["value"]=> string(5) "34001" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#1833 (2) { ["dept"]=> string(11) "Engineering" ["value"]=> string(5) "34002" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#1832 (2) { ["dept"]=> string(7) "Quality" ["value"]=> string(5) "34003" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#1834 (2) { ["dept"]=> string(8) "Outsides" ["value"]=> string(5) "34004" }} }

Comment: And how about `$dept_data`?

Comment: The $dept_data : array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1839 (3) { ["user_dept_id"]=> int(34) ["user_id"]=> int(46) ["department_id"]=> int(34001) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#1838 (3) { ["user_dept_id"]=> int(35) ["user_id"]=> int(46) ["department_id"]=> int(34002) } }

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with

```
$dept_data = DB::table('user_department')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
```

The above code would return an collection, hence you'd need to loop through `$dept_data` . If you want an single model instance, replace the `get()` call with `first()` or `find()` or cast the collection to an array or get the results in an array format using `pluck()`.

so replacing the above code with

```
$dept_data = DB::table('user_department')
                     ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                     ->pluck('department_id');
```

would work for

```
@foreach($dept as $depts)
<option value="{{ $depts->value }}" {{ in_array($depts->value, $dept_data) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>
    {{ $depts->dept }}
</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: ya definately it works, but i need with get(), because i am using it for multiselect edit purpose so need more than one fields. :)

Comment: Still i am getting error message : Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\betashim\app\views\users\edit.blade.php)"

Answer (score 0):

Might be the issue with `$dept_data`, check this if this has some value or blank?

If your below query return value then it should work:

```
$dept_data = DB::table('user_department')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();
```

Comment: Yes, it has value in database.

Comment: Can you please print and compare `$dept` and `$dept_data`, from this we can get some help and solution

Comment: can you please come to chat i will show you the results of both $dept and $dept_data.